# how to set variable to default selection on select statement and also list choice from an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Im currently using a select statement for a dropdown box to select from multiple products. On an edit form i want the select to automatically select the choice that was originally chosen which is stored in the variable $product. Im using an array to bring in all choices from the database table however can't get the array to work aswell as select the data stored in $product.

The code i've currently got is;

```
  $selectquery = "SELECT * FROM `loanproducts`";
  $selectresult = mysqli_query($connection, $selectquery);



  <select name="product" style="width: 150px">
    <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($selectresult)):;?>
    <option><?php echo $row1[1];?></option>
    <?php endwhile;?>
  </select></p></div>
```

Im not sure if I've explained what im trying to do well enough as it is confusing me even trying to explain.

-Basically for example I have 3 choices from the array- A, B & C.
-If the user goes through the form and selects B, when I then go to edit their choices I want their option to appear in the select box (B) - rather than the first choice on the array which would presumably be A

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed a little your programming style which is not very confortable to me. Anyway, the important thing here is that I create the variable `$selected` with two possible values : `""` or `"selected"`, depending if the current product (`$row1[1]`) is equal to the product selected (`$product`). All options but one will get `""`, only the selected product will get `"selected"` :

```
<select name="product" style="width: 150px">
<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($selectresult))
      { if ( $row1[1] == $product ) // IF CURRENT PRODUCT WAS SELECTED
             $selected = "selected";
        else $selected = "";
        echo "<option $selected>{$row1[1]}</option>";
      }
?>
</select></p></div>
```